# Pyspark DataFrame - propagate column subset onto another DataFrame's column

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Using Python 3.9, I have Spark DataFrame (just an example):

**DataFrame A**:

| id | Name | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Michael | null |
| 8 | Dwight | null |
| 17 | Darryl | null |

After some computing I get a subset of **DataFrame A**, containing only people working in specific **Place** like so:

**DataFrame B**:

| id | Name | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Michael | Office |
| 8 | Dwight | Office |

Please note: All entries in **DataFrame B** column **Place** always have same values  (like for example "Office" here or "Warehouse" in some other computation).

My question is: how to "propagate" column **Place** from **DataFrame B** into **DataFrame A**? Resulting propagation should look like:

**DataFrame C**:

| id | Name | Place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Michael | Office |
| 8 | Dwight | Office |
| 17 | Darryl | null |

Tried using sth like with no luck:

```
row_list = B.select('id').collect()
B_ids = [row.id for row in row_list]
A.withColumn('Place', when(A['id'].isin(B_ids), 'Office'))
```

Comment: What is the error? Also please edit your data example format

Comment: Thanks for pointing editing issues out. There is no error - either all entries in DataFrame C column Place are "Office" or null after executing provided piece of code.

Comment: I feel in third line you were looking for A.withColumn('Place', when(A['id'].isin(B_ids), 'Office')) instead of B

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi True. Sorry for that - corrected.

Comment: No I meant to create dataframe C you will want to use A at start also along with A['id'] cause only A has 3 rows while B has only 2

Comment: I'm guessing what you want is `.join()`

Comment: @samkart Tried several different approaches with join, couldn't find a right one tho. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AnjaneyaTripathi Again true. Sorry for sloppiness. Corrected. (Trust me, in my actual code tried correct line)

Comment: based on the sample dataframes, you'd want to join df_b with df_a on `id` and `name`. drop `place` from df_a and retain the `place` field form df_b

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.